# Custom 404 page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-404, custom-pages

I am beginner in ruby and cant find solution how to create custom 404-401 page in Rails 5. 
Any suggestion?
I've created a controller "ErrorPages" with action "page_404".
Help me please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :on_record_not_found
  rescue_from AbstractController::ActionNotFound, with: :on_record_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :on_routing_error
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied, with: :on_access_denied

  def render_404
    if params[:format].present? && params[:format] != 'html'
      head status: 404
    else
      render 'application/404', status: 404
    end
  end

  def on_access_denied
    if params[:format].present? && params[:format] != 'html'
      head status: 401
    else
      render 'application/401', status: 401
    end
  end

  def on_record_not_found
    render_404
  end

  def on_routing_error
    render_404
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#render_404'
end
```

/app/views/application/404.html.slim

```
.content
 .row
  .col-md-12
    h1 404
```

Comment: less than a minute ? .... Seems like you pasted code from your project as it is...

Comment: Do you own both of these accounts?

Comment: I just keep these questions in https://www.evernote.com
for example 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s554/sh/5b04e531-758c-45b6-8f28-1a9a53fd3e6c/97bd855e98482cd808a5ba7ea46fd2e5

Comment: 301 redirect https://www.evernote.com/shard/s554/sh/e3633d93-2e5c-4ef9-8d2c-89b7ad442766/23e9770a5ef2e4f3ea00129da78368b7